# Transfer files remotelly via delayed rendering+CF_HDROP

Tags: c++, winapi, clipboard

I'm trying to develop a remote file transfer. The server application downloads files to a temporary folder. At the very beginning of the download, `SetClipboardData(CF_HDROP, NULL)` is called. And then pressing Ctrl-V is simulated, in order to transfer file paths in the `WM_RENDERFORMAT` handler after downloading the files. The problem is that the `WM_RENDERFORMAT` message arrives even without Ctrl-V simulation. I noticed that if there are no open folders at the start of the program, it does not come, if there is at least one opened folder, the message will definitely come. It's likely that I'm wrong somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070918-00/?p=25083

Comment: Why would you want to run the risk of someone requesting the `CF_HDROP` format before the files are ready? Just because you are relying on Ctrl-V to transfer the files over a remote connection does not mean you have to put the `CF_HDROP` format onto the clipboard while the files are still downloading. That seems a little counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: Yes, I already realized (thanks to Raymond) that using `CF_HDROP` for these purposes was the wrong decision. Now I'm trying to figure out how to organize this using `FileGroupDescriptor`, which looks a bit complicated, given that all the examples I found in C# while I have a C++ desktop application :)

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080319-00/?p=23073

Comment: Raymond, thank you for the link. I tried this example and it works good. But in my case I don't know where user is trying to past files to (is it folder or some file manager or anything else). If it would be drag-and-drop - it would be more easy (at least I have your example code), but I have to use "Ctrl-V" method (client is browser-based and runs at fullscreen). That's why I tried use `CF_HDROP`.

Comment: Put the data object on the clipboard and everything works the same as drag/drop.

Comment: Yeah, It works. Thank you! But it works, when the file which I want to copy is exists already. In my case, the file does not exist at the moment of pressing Ctrl-V - it will start loading immediately after that. Is IStream supports delayed rendering?

Comment: You control the IStream. You can delay the download until somebody reads from the IStream.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe I don't fully understand how IStream works (lack of information in MSDN or I'm missing something). Now my code looks like this - I create an instance of `Dataobject` (took your `CTinyDataObject` as a basis) and put it on the clipboard. When user pastes something (Ctrl-V for example) the 'CTinyDataObject::getData' works out - for the `CFSTR_FILECONTENTS` format I create an `IStream` using the `SHCreateStreamOnFileW` and put it in the medium `pstm` field. But AFAIU Windows immediately copies the file (transferred to `IStream`) and that's it, but I need to download it first.

Comment: Then download the file before calling SHCreateStreamOnFileW. IStream represents virtual content. You don't even have to have a file. You can produce the data on demand in response to IStream::Read. IStream::Read means "Please give me the next bytes of data." You decide what that data is. Get it from a file, download it from the internet, calculate it on the fly, it's all up to you.

Comment: Thank you, Raymond! I've finally done it (created my own IStream class). And special thanks for your patience:)

Comment: Maybe you can post a solution to help the next person.

Comment: Indeed, will do it soon!

Comment: @Liverpoolfan Any luck posting the solution?

Comment: Hi, Raymod! Yeah, there were several business trips after I finished working on this, as well as a long vacation. But I'm posting the solution as promised. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I created my own `MyDataObject` class based on `IDataObject` (Raymond Chan has written some excellent articles on this topic - https://github.com/mity/old-new-win32api#drag-and-drop).
In fact, all the difference between my class and `CTinyDataObject` from Raymond's articles in the constructor and the `GetData` method.

Constructor:

```
MyDataObject::MyDataObject(std::vector<FileInfo>& fileList) :
    refCnt_(1),
    fileList_(fileList) {
    FORMATETC format;
    SetFORMATETC(&format, RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR));
    formats_.push_back(format);

    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
        SetFORMATETC(&format, RegisterClipboardFormat(CFSTR_FILECONTENTS), TYMED_ISTREAM, i);
        formats_.push_back(format);
    }
}
```

`fileList_` - a class variable that stores a vector of such structures

```
struct FileInfo {
    int fileSize;
    std::wstring path;
    std::wstring fileName;
    bool canOpenFile = false;
    IStream* stream_ = nullptr;
};
```

`GetData`:

```
HRESULT MyDataObject::GetData(FORMATETC* pfe, STGMEDIUM* pmed) {
    ZeroMemory(pmed, sizeof(*pmed));
    auto format = GetDataIndex(pfe);
    if (format == DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR) {
        int fgd_size = sizeof(FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR) + (fileList_.size() - 1) * sizeof(FILEDESCRIPTOR);
        LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR fgd = (LPFILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR)new BYTE[fgd_size];
        ZeroMemory(fgd, sizeof(fgd));
        fgd->cItems = fileList_.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList_.size(); i++) {
            fgd->fgd[i].dwFlags = FD_FILESIZE;
            fgd->fgd[i].nFileSizeHigh = 0;
            fgd->fgd[i].nFileSizeLow = fileList_[i].fileSize;
            StringCchCopy(fgd->fgd[i].cFileName, ARRAYSIZE(fgd->fgd[i].cFileName), fileList_[i].fileName.c_str());
        }

        pmed->tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
        return CreateHGlobalFromBlob(fgd, fgd_size, GMEM_MOVEABLE, &pmed->hGlobal);
    }
    else if (format > DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR && format <= DATA_FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR + fileList_.size()) {
        pmed->tymed = TYMED_ISTREAM;

        fileList_[pfe->lindex].stream_ = new MyIStream();
        if (fileList_[pfe->lindex].canOpenFile) {
            MyIStream* stream = (MyIStream*)fileList_[pfe->lindex].stream_;
            stream->OpenFile(fileList_[pfe->lindex].path.c_str());
        }

        pmed->pstm = fileList_[pfe->lindex].stream_;

        return S_OK;
    }

    return DV_E_FORMATETC;
}
```

In order to express the contents of a virtual file, I defined my IStream class. It also does not differ much from the standard:

```
class MyIStream : public IStream {
public:

    HRESULT OpenFile(LPCWSTR pName);

    ....

private:
    std::mutex mutex_;
    HANDLE _hFile = nullptr;
};

HRESULT MyIStream::OpenFile(LPCWSTR pName) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
    _hFile = ::CreateFile(pName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    if (_hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE MyIStream::Read(void* pv, ULONG cb, ULONG* pcbRead) {
    while (true) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex_);
            if (_hFile) {
                break;
            }
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }

    BOOL rc = ReadFile(_hFile, pv, cb, pcbRead, NULL);
    return S_OK;
}
```

How I use this in my main app. Initially, I get a complete list of files to download from the client and create a separate thread:

```
void MyAppClass::fileCopyThread() {
    if (SUCCEEDED(OleInitialize(NULL))) {
        fileCopyThreadId_ = GetCurrentThreadId();

        IDataObject* pdto = new MyDataObject(filesDesc_);
        if (pdto) {
            OleSetClipboard(pdto);
            pdto->Release();
        }
        // simulate Ctrl-V
        ...
        // process messages
        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        OleSetClipboard(NULL);
        OleUninitialize();
    }
}
```

When the file is fully loaded, I call the `FileInfo.OpenFile` method (or set the `FileInfo.canOpenFile` flag to true if MyDataObject::GetData has not been called yet - this happens, for example, if the file is small and was downloaded very fast).

After all files from the remote are downloaded we need to call this:

```
PostThreadMessage(fileCopyThreadId_, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
```